# Why jspdf seems to add padding to this image

Tags: reactjs, canvas, jspdf

I need the Image to fill the whole pdf and the pdf height and width have to come from the image

I tested the image and there is no problems with just the image file

```
exportToPDF = () => {
    var imgData = this.state.canvasRef.toDataURL("image");
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imgData;
    document.body.appendChild(image)



    var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "px", [this.state.canvasRef.getWidth(), this.state.canvasRef.getHeight()]);
    pdf.addImage(image, 'png', 0, 0);
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
    console.log("export to PDF clicked");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are putting your image into the canvas but I assume you are doing something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trycanvas_image. If so then the padding could be being added before you are using jspdf.

In this example the line `ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);` is adding padding to the image on the canvas. If this is whats happening to you then change this line to `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);` and then change the height and width of your canvas tag to match the size of your img tag.